# In MySQL, how to select data based on date?

Tags: mysql, date

I need to get record based on date but I got stuck.

```
rate  applicable_date

12        01/01/2001
13.5      01/05/2005
17.9      07/11/2017
```

I need to get applicable rate based on applicable date. I used below SQL:

```
Select rate from ratetable where applicable_date <=$date;
```

For `$date = '12/02/2017'`;

It returns me `12`

but for date 17/11/2017 it returns me all rates but I need only 17.9 latest one.

Comment: show your query

Comment: Select rate from ratetable where applicable_date <=$date;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select rate 
from ratetable 
where applicable_date <=$date
order by desc
limit 1;
```

now it will return only 17.9

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following query

```
select rate from ratetable where applicable_date = $date
```